# Throw an intentional exception to stop program executing in Java

Tags: java, exception

I put an exception intentionally to stop program executing but it seems that the executions continues after the exception is thrown.

```
try{
   System.out.println("Executing ");
   throw new RuntimeException("This is thrown intentionally");
} catch {....
}
System.out.println("Must not execute");
```

I don't want to use `System.exit()` since I don't want to stop JVM and don't want to use `return` since I want it look like an error happened. Please help to on this.

Comment: `catch {` where did you specify exception

Comment: You do know what a `catch` block is for, don't you?

Comment: After your edit, you should include whatever you have in your catch block. Perhaps you are catching the exception.

Comment: I know what is a catch block. But just imagine that I want to throw that exception intentionally.

Comment: Then don't catch it after you've thrown it

Comment: and you think your code "knows" whether that exception is thrown intentionally or not? no matter why it is thrown, once it is caught and handled, for the application it's no longer an issue.

Comment: If you want to "stop a program executing" but you don't want to "stop JVM", why not just return from the method? Exceptions should only be used indicate exceptional conditions, not normal completion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to catch the exception after it is thrown. If you catch it there, the program will start executing the statements that are there after the catch block.

```
System.out.println("Executing ");
if(1 == 1) // I put this 'if' here so that the code compiles
{
     throw new RuntimeException("This is thrown intentionally");
}
System.out.println("Must not execute");
```